# Failing a test Case in finding the first and last position of element using binary search

Tags: c++, binary-search

Given an array of integers nums sorted in non-decreasing order, find the starting and ending position of a given target value.

If target is not found in the array, return [-1, -1].

You must write an algorithm with O(log n) runtime complexity.

I wrote this code in leetcode but it has only passed 67 test cases out of 88.Can someone please tell me the problem with this code.

```
class Solution {
public:
int FirstOccurence(vector<int> arr, int n, int x) {
    int low = 0, high = n - 1;
    int ans = -1;

    while (low <= high) {
        int mid = (low + high) / 2;
        // maybe an answer
        if (arr[mid] == x) {
            ans=mid;
            high=mid-1;
    }
    else if (arr[mid]< x) {
            low=mid+1;
    }
    else high=mid-1;
    }
    return ans;
}

int LastOccurence(vector<int> arr, int n, int x) {
    int low = 0, high = n - 1;
    int ans = -1;

    while (low <= high) {
        int mid = (low + high) / 2;
        // maybe an answer
        if (arr[mid]== x) {
            ans = mid;
            //look for smaller index on the left
            low=mid+1;
        }
        else if(arr[mid]>x){
            high=mid-1;
        }
        else {
            low = mid + 1; // look on the right
        }
    }
    return ans;
}
    vector<int> searchRange(vector<int>& nums, int target) {
        int n=nums.size()-1;
        int k=target;
        int a=FirstOccurence(nums,n,k);
    int b=LastOccurence(nums,n,k);
    return{a,b};
    }
};
```

Comment: As far as I know, Leetcode is on the better side of the so-called "competition" or "judge" sites, because it gives you the failed test-case. You can take that test-case, hard-code it into a [mre], and then [*debug*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your code locally on your own system.

Comment: The `n` argument is the largest valid index, and `high` is one less than that, so you can never look at the last element. (Get used to the conventional half-open intervals and stick to them.)

Comment: *Can someone please tell me the problem with this code.* -- [What is a debugger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems).

Comment: FYI -- you don't need to write any binary search function to solve this problem.  The [std:::lower_bound/upper_bound](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) functions already do the search and will return iterators to either the target element, or to the element before/after the target, or `nums.end()` if the target isn't in `nums`.  From there, it is some simple logic to clean things up and return the `std::distance` to the iterators.

Comment: `int mid = (low + high) / 2;` -- `low + high` will cause an overflow if there are many elements.

Comment: [Quick and dirty solution](https://godbolt.org/z/KcoTrPz7j).  Note the usage of `std::lower_bound` and `std::upper_bound`.  If you're going to use Leetcode, know your algorithm functions such as `std::lower_bound/upper_bound` so that the questions can be easily answered (instead of writing (buggy) code from scratch).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I added an opition using `std::equal_range` to the answer.

Comment: @TedLyngmo -- Yes, that is even better than my solution.  The bottom line is to know how to utilize C++ in answering the Leetcode questions efficiently, which the OP was not doing.

Comment: Consider posting here: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

You are sending in `nums.size() - 1` to the binary search functions and inside them you make `high = n - 1`, effectively making `high = nums.size() - 2` so all tests where the `target` is the greatest number in the `vector` will fail.

An easy fix would be to not send in `n` at all. You already send in the `vector` and can call `.size()` inside the functions:

```cpp
int FirstOccurence(const std::vector<int>& arr, int x) {  // no `n`
    int low = 0, high = static_cast<int>(arr.size()) - 1; // size() - 1 instead
```

```cpp
int LastOccurence(const std::vector<int>& arr, int x) {   // no `n`
    int low = 0, high = static_cast<int>(arr.size()) - 1; // size() - 1 instead
```

Then at the call site:

```cpp
std::vector<int> searchRange(const std::vector<int>& nums, int target) {
    int k = target;
    int a = FirstOccurence(nums, k); // no `n`
    int b = LastOccurence(nums, k);  // no `n`
    return {a, b};
}
```

---

An alternative could be to use [`std::equal_range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal_range) from the standard library:

```
#include <algorithm> // equal_range
#include <iterator>  // distance

std::vector<int> searchRange(const std::vector<int>& nums, int target) {
    std::vector<int> res{-1, -1};
    auto [fit, lit] = std::equal_range(nums.begin(), nums.end(), target);

    if (fit != lit) {
        res[0] = static_cast<int>(std::distance(nums.begin(), fit));
        res[1] = static_cast<int>(std::distance(nums.begin(), lit)) - 1;
    }
    return res;
}
```